# Choices not being rendered in template

Tags: django, forms, materialize

Working in Django. I've added choices and the necessary field in my model. The choices are well populated in the admin site, but not rendered in the template.
I've double checked several times and everything seems right so I don't understand why the choices aren't rendered in the template. Could it be related to the CSS? I'm using materialize.

I've added the .input-field class and initialized the select element as per the materialize documentation.
Nothing changed.

This is my code:

model:

```
class Grocery(models.Model):
    """
    Model to create a grocery_list
    """
    CATEGORIES = [("groceries", "Groceries"),
                  ("school", "School"),
                  ("hardware", "Hardware"),
                  ("travel", "Travel"),
                  ("gifts", "Gifts"),
                  ("decoration", "Decoration"),
                  ("lifestyle", "Lifestyle"),
                  ("wishlist", "Wishlist")]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='My grocery list')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORIES,
                                default='Shopping')
```

form:

```
class GroceryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form to create a grocery shopping list
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Grocery
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'shop', 'item']
```

template:

```
{% block title %}Create shopping list{% endblock %} 

{% block content %}

<div class="container row">
  <div class="col s10 m8 push-s1 push-m2">
    <h1 class="center-align">Create a grocery shopping list</h1>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="input-field section">
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.media }} {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect btn">Create list</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

JS

```
// sidebar initialization
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      let sidenav = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav");
      M.Sidenav.init(sidenav);
    });

    // select initialization
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      let elems = document.querySelectorAll("select");
      M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `M.FormSelect.init(elems, options)` but you did not define `options` in the first place, so the initialization fails.

Have a look to your javascript console and you will see this error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined`.

I tried removing it and its working just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @May.D I've just read your message. In the meantime I found that my materialize set up was uncomplete as well. It's working now.